# Errors when I run NPM start

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on building a RESTful API using Node, express, and MongoDB.
During the beginning stages of this project, when I attempt to run the "npm start", I get a few lines of errors.

[The errors I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu8Ql.png)

I'm not sure what the problem could be as I have added the "start" under scripts in the package.json file and I have initialized node and well as having installed nodemon. Please may I ask for assistance?

Comment: It says there is additional loggin above. Can you show the whole log please?

Comment: Could you post whats inside app.js?

Comment: Please post the actual text of the any relevant code or error messages (not just an image).  [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816/1563833).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Make the file `index.js`
2. Try the command `node app.js`, if it works then your `node_modules` is in the wrong place or you dependencies are probably not installed properly.
3. Try uninstalling and installing dependencies.